# firebase Function - how to define region location

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I noticed when I first do firebase deploy for Firebase Function
it seems to default to

```
✔  functions[helloWorld(us-central1)]: Successful create operation.
```

where should I define the region for the function ?

Here are the generated code from firebase function - firebase init
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/9a9edee075860683153155e6277f2a08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the region like this:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.region("europe-west2").https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

You can read more about it and check a list of available regions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations).